# Angularjs + nodejs + passport cross domain request

Tags: node.js, angularjs, cross-domain, cors, passport-facebook

I'm using passport with facebook strategy for authentication. Problem doesn't reside in the back-end which is nodejs, as i have tested without angularjs and everything works just fine, but whenever angularjs comes into play i'd get `CORS` error.

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is present on the requested resource. Origin `host:8000` is therefore not allowed access.

I have tried most of the solutions i have found via google, but nothing has really worked so far. Does anyone have an idea what might be wrong?

This is the most common answer usually to this sort of question as far as i understand.

```
site.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
});
```

And like i said, it is not nodejs fault.

Comment: I had a similar problem when I was trying to call an external API directly from angular using $http.get. I didn't manage to resolve that but as a workaround I created a module in backend(nodejs) which calls the external API and angular communicates with the backend.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a popup to get around the CORS issue with Angular.. see this post for an example: http://www.webdeveasy.com/single-page-application-authentication/